# Get random emails address from CSV file

Tags: email, csv, random

anyone know how to randomly show email load from csv file ?

This is my code :

```
<?php 
function random_phrase () 
{ 
$quotes = file ("Bounced_Email.csv");
$num = rand(1,10 intval (count ($quotes))) * 10;
echo $quotes[$num] . "<br>" . $quotes[$num + 1];
}
?>
<?php random_phrase (10);?>
```

Actually i want to show 10 emails from my CSV file (randomly)
but not sure why still show error.

anyone can help ? please

Thanks

Comment: How about reading all lines into some container, then extracting 10 lines randomly from the container?

Comment: Hi bro, what i want to do is : just show 10 emails ID, then if i refresh will come new 10 emails is different from the 1st one...

just show 10 email / 1 time refresh.